# Why I can access to variable that's outside of class in that class

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to understand why I have acces to that object `formOptions` from my Class `formValidate`.

I mean maybe I still thinking like Python language work but in my mind this isn't supposed to have access because we need to give class constructor that `formOptions` object.

```
const formOptions = {
  defaultValue: "Write:",
  colorFocus: "red",
  errorSize: 15
};

class formValidate {
  constructor(form) {
    this.form = form;
    console.log(formOptions);
  }
}
```

Can you explain me how scoping for Class work ?

Comment: Every function in JavaScript is a closure. I.e. every function has access to all variables defined in the scope it is defined itself. You'd also have access to that variable in Python btw.

Answer (score 0):

`formOptions` and `formValidate` share the same outer scope. In JavaScript, where the tradition is **lexical scoping** (function scope), we could say that they are at the same level of the **scope chain**.

It is true that ES6 introduced **block scoping**, especially with `const` and `let`. But apparently, you did not get it... `const` does not create a local scope. It just lives in the block scope in which it has been defined. If you want to isolate your `formOptions`, you can use the good old trick and encapsulate your constant in a function like so:

```js
function foo() {
  const formOptions = {
    defaultValue: "Write:",
    colorFocus: "red",
    errorSize: 15
  };
}

class FormValidate {
  constructor(form) {
    this.form = form;

    // ReferenceError
    console.log(formOptions);
  }
}

let fv = new FormValidate();
```

But since `const` is block scoped, it will also work with whatever block. Here are some examples:

```js
{
  const formOptions = {
    defaultValue: "Write:",
    colorFocus: "red",
    errorSize: 15
  };
}

class FormValidate {
  constructor(form) {
    this.form = form;

    // ReferenceError
    console.log(formOptions);
  }
}

let fv = new FormValidate();
```

```js
if (true) {
  const formOptions = {
    defaultValue: "Write:",
    colorFocus: "red",
    errorSize: 15
  };
}

class FormValidate {
  constructor(form) {
    this.form = form;

    // ReferenceError
    console.log(formOptions);
  }
}

let fv = new FormValidate();
```

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  const formOptions = {
    defaultValue: "Write:",
    colorFocus: "red",
    errorSize: 15
  };
}

class FormValidate {
  constructor(form) {
    this.form = form;

    // ReferenceError
    console.log(formOptions);
  }
}

let fv = new FormValidate();
```